# How to compare two rows in SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql-server

I want to compare with two rows by columns, they look like this:

```
    The rows 1,columns 1 compare to the other row 2,columns 1.
    The rows 1,columns 2 compare to the other row 2,columns 2.
    The rows 1,columns 3 compare to the other row 2,columns 3.
    The rows 1,columns 4 compare to the other row 2,columns 4.
    ........
```

And the logic will be:

```
if the rows 1 columns 1 equal to  rows 2,columns 1    
    do something
else    
    do other thing
.........
```

How to do this?

```
a. The two rows in the same table.
b. There are only two rows in the table
```

I want to use cursor in procedure but can not access it! Thank you!

Comment: "I want to use cursor" - maybe so, but you probably *shouldn't*. Are there *only* two rows in this table? Or are there *pairs* of rows? (how are the pairs identified?). Or should each row be compared with "the previous row"? (In which case, what defines the order such that "previous" is defined?) Or are these rows in different tables? (In which case, how do we pair up between the tables?)

Comment: Go on keep on editing  your question because it's still not clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this - I hope this helps you. I'm assuming there are at least 2 rows in your table (based on your 3rd sentence):

```
DECLARE cursor_name FOR
SELECT ID, Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4
FROM    [YOUR TABLE]
[YOUR WHERE CLAUSE HERE IF ANY]

OPEN cursor_name

DECLARE @CurID int
DECLARE @CurCol1 varchar(25)
DECLARE @CurCol2 varchar(25)
DECLARE @CurCol3 varchar(25)
DECLARE @CurCol4 varchar(25)

DECLARE @PrevID int
DECLARE @PrevCol1 varchar(25)
DECLARE @PrevCol2 varchar(25)
DECLARE @PrevCol3 varchar(25)
DECLARE @PrevCol4 varchar(25)

--Get First Row
FETCH NEXT FROM cursor_name 
INTO @PrevID, @PrevCol1, @PrevCol2, @PrevCol3, @PrevCol4

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

    --Get Next Row
    FETCH NEXT FROM cursor_name 
    INTO @CurID, @CurCol1, @CurCol2, @CurCol3, @CurCol4

    --COMPARE
    IF @PrevCol1 = @CurCol1
        AND @PrevCol2 = @CurCol2
        AND @PrevCol3 = @CurCol3
        AND @PrevCol4 = @CurCol4
    BEGIN       
        --DO SOMTHING   
    END
    ELSE BEGIN
        --DO SOMETHING
    END

    --STORE CURRENT ROW
    SET @PrevCol1 = @CurCol1
    SET @PrevCol2 = @CurCol2
    SET @PrevCol3 = @CurCol3
    SET @PrevCol4 = @CurCol4

END

CLOSE cursor_name
DEALLOCATE cursor_name
```

Comment: Thank you,i have not any better solution.I will do like what you say!